# ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE is not working for multiple column in mysql 5.1

Tags: php, mysql, sql, phpmyadmin, on-duplicate-key

I have a table `test` with following structure:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `test` (
  `id` int(11) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `user_id` int(11) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `lat` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
  `long` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
  `updatedon` datetime NOT NULL,
  `addedon` datetime NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  UNIQUE KEY `user_id` (`user_id`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM  DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 AUTO_INCREMENT=3 ;
```

and I am trying to use following queries none are working:

```
INSERT INTO `test` (`user_id`, `lat`, `long`)
 VALUES ('1', 'latv', 'longv')
ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE
  lat=VALUES(lat),
long = VALUES(long)

INSERT INTO `test` (`user_id`, `lat`, `long`)
 VALUES ('1', 'latv', 'longv')
ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE
  lat="test_lat",
long = "test_long"
```

here is the error for one query:

```
#1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'long = VALUES(long)' at line 5
```

I am trying this in phpmyadmin.

Comment: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/keywords.html **LONG (R)**

Comment: thanks. I changed the field name from long to user_long and now it is working. It was the issue of reserved word LONG.

Comment: If you want to continue using `long`, you can. You just need to wrap all of those with ticks `\`` as you did for the others. @ErFaiyazAlam

Comment: @Fred-ii-. thanks. It also worked.

Comment: @ErFaiyazAlam you're welcome. *Cheers*